# Git client and server on same machine

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, https

In our environment, I want to introduce the Git server [Bonobo](https://bonobogitserver.com/) and automation server [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/). I've installed both components on the same machine, each of them has it's own DNS alias (*buildserver.mycompany.com* and *scm.mycompany.com*).

Now I want Jenkins to clone the source code from Bonobo via HTTPS, so I enter: 
`git clone https://scm.mycompany.com`

Bonobo has been configured for HTTPS, of course. I also configured the certificate store (ca-bundle.crt) of Jenkins' Git client, because the used certificate is self-signed.
Everything I do results in `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to scm.mycompany.com:443`.
I've tested several other computers and accounts with the same configuration (same Git client, same Git certificate store, etc.), it is always working.

Is it possible that the connection fails because Git client and server are trying to communicate via HTTPS, but are located on the same machine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it on my own, the proxy was responsible.